# How to copy paste a range from google sheet and send it on email using app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am not sure if I am asking the right question. I may sound dumb but please do consider my request. I want to create a appscript that can send email like this. I want my appscript to select the range and send the email just like the screenshot attached below
[image]

Comment: How is the content of your email derived from what you have? And what is it that you have? Take a moment to read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the guide on [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can be helpful too.

Comment: I did nothing. I just copy pasted the range in the mail body. I just want to know how can I automate this using google app-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID here');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:C4').getValues(); //this is just a sample range from the sheet
  var msg = ""

  msg = "<table><tr><td><b>Product</td><td><b>Stocks</td><td><b>Price</td></b></tr>"
  for(var i = 0; i < range.length; i++){
    msg += "<tr>"
    msg += "<td>" + range[i] + "</td>"
    msg += "</tr>"
  }
  msg += "</table>"
  Logger.log(range); 

  GmailApp.sendEmail("Email recipient here", "Test Email"," ", {htmlBody:msg});
}
```

For the table design, this can be done by doing CSS inline with the HTML Tags.

Reference:

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)
2. https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
3. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp